# How do you autoresize a subview of a UITableViewCell for grouped mode?

Tags: uitableview, autoresizingmask

I've subclassed UITableViewCell to add an extra label and some color options.

I added the label as a subview of [the cell].contentView. When you set a UITableView to "grouped" mode, it's indented from the sides of the parent view.  The default subviews are moved a corresponding amount, but not ones you add.  I set the added view's autoResizingMask to every possible value, but none takes the reduced width into account correctly.

[image: Here are all the combos and results:]

The rect for the label subview is created in initWithReuseIdentifier as follows:

```
    CGRect specialtyRect = CGRectMake(IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_SIZE + 3, 3, self.contentView.frame.size.width - IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_SIZE - 6, 16);
    self.specialtyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:specialtyRect];
    [self.contentView addSubview:specialtyLabel];
```

Does anyone know why the red subview is behaving this way, and how to make the right end indent correctly to match the reduced width while the left end remains correctly offset from the imageView?  Thanks!

I'm not using a UITableViewController, and I'm not loading these cells from a XIB.